# Finding the tension in a 3D circular motion problem with little information

Tags: classical-mechanics, circular-motion

[image]

I've been stuck on this for some time now; to find the tension I would **resolve** both **vertically** and **horizontally** towards the centre of the circle that P travels on - but for this, I require **$\sin$/$\cos$** of the angle the rod makes, which in turn requires the radius of P's motion and one other side. I can't deduce this from the text. Is there some other way in which I should be approaching this? I just can't find a way to solve it using alternative methods. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since the radius is perpendicular to the tangent (rod), the angle $\theta$ between the rod and the vertical is given by $$\sin\theta=\frac{r}{2r}=\frac12$$

I hope this helps.